# JSONModel iOS and Polymorphism

Tags: ios, json, model-view-controller, model, jsonmodel

Using the following models as examples, what are the best practices of handling polymorphism within [JSONModel](https://github.com/icanzilb/JSONModel)?

```
@interface GameModel : JSONModel
@property (nonatomic, assign) long id;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSArray<GameEventModel> *events;
/*
  ...
*/
@end

@interface GameEventModel : JSONModel
@property (nonatomic, assign) long long timestamp;
/*
  ...
*/
@end

@interface GameTouchEventModel : GameEventModel
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGPoint point;
/*
  ...
*/
@end
```

When GameModel is initiated with a JSON string of `{id:1, events:[{point:{x:1, y:1}, timestamp:...}]}`

JSONModel will use the `GameEventModel` and ignore the `point` property.

Would it be better to use a generic `GameEventModel` which contains a `type` property and `info` property such as...

```
@interface GameTouchEventModel : GameEventModel
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *type;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *info;
@end
```

And therefore the model could accept JSON as `{id:1, events:[{ type:"GameTouchEventModel", info:{ point:{x:1, y:1}, timestamp:... } }]}`

The problem with this approach is harder to read code and no compiler warnings/errors amongst others.

Is there no way to use polymorphic models in JSONModel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We solved this with 2 minor alterations to `JSONModel.m`, introducing a new special JSON property `__subclass` which is picked up by the `JSONModel` parser and uses the value as the object type. `__subclass` is  required to be a reserved keyword (therefore no models can use `__subclass` as a property name).

Alterations to `JSONModel.m`

```
// ...
-(id)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary*)dict error:(NSError**)err
{
      // ...
      if ([self __isJSONModelSubClass:property.type]) {

            //initialize the property's model, store it
            JSONModelError* initErr = nil;

            -- id value = [[property.type alloc] initWithDictionary: jsonValue error:&initErr];

            ++ id value;
            ++ if([jsonValue valueForKey:@"subclass"] != NULL)
            ++ {
            ++       Class jsonSubclass = NSClassFromString([d valueForKey:@"subclass"]);
            ++       if(jsonSubclass)
            ++             obj = [[jsonSubclass alloc] initWithDictionary:d error:&initErr];
            ++ }
            ++ else
            ++     value = [[property.type alloc] initWithDictionary: jsonValue error:&initErr];
       //...
//...
+(NSMutableArray*)arrayOfModelsFromDictionaries:(NSArray*)array error:(NSError**)err
{
      // ...
      for (NSDictionary* d in array) {
           JSONModelError* initErr = nil;

           -- id obj = [[self alloc] initWithDictionary:d error:&initErr];

           ++ id obj;
           ++ if([d valueForKey:@"subclass"] != NULL)
           ++ {
           ++       Class jsonSubclass = NSClassFromString([d valueForKey:@"subclass"]);
           ++       if(jsonSubclass)
           ++             obj = [[jsonSubclass alloc] initWithDictionary:d error:&initErr];
           ++ }
           ++ else
           ++      obj = [[self alloc] initWithDictionary:d error:&initErr];
       // ...
 // ...
```

NOTE: If the `_subclass`'ed JSON model class doesn't exist, then the model will fallback to the superclass.

This will then work with the following models

```
@interface GameModel : JSONModel
@property (nonatomic, assign) long id;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSArray<GameEventModel> *events;
@end

@protocol GameEventModel
@end

@interface GameEventModel : JSONModel
@property (nonatomic, assign) long long timestamp;
@end

@interface GameTouchEventModel : GameEventModel
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *point;
@end
```

When passed the JSON string `{id:1, events:[ { __subclass:'GameTouchEventModel', timestamp:1, point: [0,0] } ] }`

Answer (score 0):

I think [BWJSONMatcher](https://github.com/BurrowsWang/BWJSONMatcher) can handle it in a very neat way.

Declare your model as follows:

```
@interface GameModel : NSObject<BWJSONValueObject>
@property (nonatomic, assign) long id;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *events;
@end

@interface GameEventModel : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, assign) long long timestamp;
@end

@interface GameTouchEventModel : GameEventModel
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *point;
@end
```

In the implementation of *GameModel*, implement this function:

```
- (Class)typeInProperty:(NSString *)property {
    if ([property isEqualToString:@"events"]) {
        return [GameEventModel class];
    }

    return nil;
}
```

And then your can get your own data instance from json string within one line:

```
GameModel *gameModel = [GameModel fromJSONString:jsonString];
```

The examples about how to use **BWJSONMatcher** to handle polymorphism can be found [here](https://github.com/BurrowsWang/BWJSONMatcher/tree/master/BWJSONMatcherTests).

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**

Using Swagger could help, see this example in [github](https://github.com/alexandern/SO22159573).

**About Swagger**

The accepted solution is one way, but I'd like to offer an alternative.  If you generate the models using [Swagger](http://swagger.io) and take advantage of the "allOf/discriminator" feature to implement inheritance, the generated Objective-C class will contain similar code to the one offered by the accepted solution.

Yaml

```
definitions:
  Point:
    type: object
    properties:
      x:
       type: number
      y:
       type: number

  GameEventModel:
    type: object
    discriminator: gameEventModelType

  GameTouchEventModel:
    type: object
    description: GameTouchEventModel
    allOf:
      - $ref: '#/definitions/GameEventModel'
      - type: object
        properties:
          gameEventModelType:
            type: string
          point:
             $ref: '#/definitions/Point'

  GameFooEventModel:
    type: object
    description: GameTouchEventModel
    allOf:
      - $ref: '#/definitions/GameEventModel'
      - type: object
        properties:
          gameEventModelType:
            type: string
          name:
             type: string

  GameModel:
    type: object
    properties:
      id:
        type: integer
        format: int64
      events:
        type: array
        items:
          $ref: '#/definitions/GameEventModel'
```

Generated code snippet

```
/**
 Maps "discriminator" value to the sub-class name, so that inheritance is supported.
 */
- (id)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict error:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)err {


    NSString * discriminatedClassName = [dict valueForKey:@"gameEventModelType"];

    if(discriminatedClassName == nil ){
         return [super initWithDictionary:dict error:err];
    }

    Class class = NSClassFromString([@"SWG" stringByAppendingString:discriminatedClassName]);

    if([self class ] == class) {
        return [super initWithDictionary:dict error:err];
    }


    return [[class alloc] initWithDictionary:dict error: err];

}
```